# Formatting Range Column S to Z based on LastRow all at Once

Tags: excel, vba

Probably a softball for all you VBA wizards out there but...

How can I select the range of S:Z all at once to format without having to select them individually ?  I tried to work with

`Range("S" & LastRow2 + 1 : "Z" & LastRow2 + 1)` but that doesn't seem to work.  Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here.

```
Range("S" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("T" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("U" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("V" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("W" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("X" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("Y" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
Range("Z" & LastRow2 + 1).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000"
```

Comment: `("S" & LastRow2 + 1 & ":Z" & LastRow2 + 1)`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!